# Recognize certain components in the compiler produced assembly program

Tags: c, assembly, compilation, static-analysis

Here is my question:

given a marked C code component, how I can find its corresponding assembly instructions in the compiler produced assembly program?

It should be very easy if the marked component is a function, as long as there is no overlapped assembly program, we can just do a linear search and recognize the function in the compiler-produced code.

Then how about the marked component is a loop statement? Or even an arithmetic statement? Is there any good solution at this time?

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: there is no reason to assume this is possible, even with a function as that can easily be inlined by the compiler.   There are situations where you can compile with no optimizations, and ask the compiler to do other things to make this easier, but in general, esp with optimization, there is not  an assumption that there is a one to one relationship between a line of code and a blob of asm.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Is "find corresponding assembly instruction" really your end goal? If you state what you are actually trying to achieve perhaps someone may have a better/easier way to do it.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically?  Just use debug info.  Or are you asking for techniques for checking how something in your C source compiled into asm?  (i.e. as a human, how to wade through bloated compiler output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `-fverbose-asm`.  gcc is much more verbose than clang with its comments in the asm output, and the variable names can help you find the loop you're looking for, but more often they're only numbered internal temporaries.  `ivtmp` might stand for iteration variable, though, as opposed to other temporaries holding results of other expressions.

```
void foo(int*p) {
  for (int i=0 ; i<123456 ; i++ )
    p[i] = p[i] * 4 - 1;
}
```

gcc 5.3 with `-fverbose-asm -O3 -march=haswell -fno-tree-vectorize -fno-unroll-loops` [compiles it to](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-fverbose-asm++-Ofast+-march%3Dhaswell+-fno-tree-vectorize+-fno-unroll-loops',source:'void+foo(int*p)+%7B%0A++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C123456+%3B+i%2B%2B+)%0A++++p%5Bi%5D+%3D+p%5Bi%5D+*+4+-+1%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) code that increments a pointer, and of course uses `lea` for the shift-and-subtract all in one.

Clang `-fverbose-asm` puts a comment on the top-of-loop branch target, but doesn't comment each line.

```
foo:
    lea     rdx, [rdi+493824] # D.2351,
.L2:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]      # MEM[base: _17, offset: 0B], MEM[base: _17, offset: 0B]
    add     rdi, 4    # ivtmp.9,
    lea     eax, [-1+rax*4]   # tmp111,
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi-4], eax    # MEM[base: _17, offset: 0B], tmp111
    cmp     rdx, rdi  # D.2351, ivtmp.9
    jne     .L2       #,
    ret
```

---

### In more complicated code:

To find inner loops, look for labels followed soon after by a branch back to the same label.  There will be labels all over the place, but you're looking for a branch back to a label with no other labels or branches in between.  (For simple loops with no flow control inside).

If the code is vectorized, look for the loop containing the vector instruction.  (e.g. lots of fully-unrolled scalar `addsd` prologue/epilogue, and then a tiny `addpd` inner loop.)

---

**Debug info also associates every instruction with a source line responsible for it**.  There are various ways to use this, including colourizing the asm output the way the Godbolt Compiler Explorer does.

[gcc auto-vectorizes this simple loop](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-fverbose-asm++-Ofast+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'void+foo(int*p)+%7B%0A++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C123456+%3B+i%2B%2B+)%0A++++p%5Bi%5D+%3D+p%5Bi%5D+*+4+-+1%3B%0A%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) into scalar code up to an aligned pointer, then a vector inner loop, then cleanup after the last full vector.  The unrolled scalar prologue/epilogue has alternating colours to mark the parts that are checking the loop condition vs. the parts doing the loop body.